# Implicit char conversion

Tags: c++

Having following code:

```
unsigned char c1 = -55;
```

1.) What happens? Is the `c1` variable implicitly converted to `unsigned int`, or is the `unsigned` ignored and `c1` remains `signed int`?

2.) Why do both these statements:

```
if (c1 != -55)  
    printf("!=");
```

and

```
if (c1 != 55)  
    printf("!=");
```

print `!=`?

Comment: Please can You tell me why was my question down-voted?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but it is a very basic question with some basic confusions embedded in it; you would probably be better off working through a C++ textbook, or several, before asking any more questions here.

Answer (score 6):

1. None of the above.  `c1` has type `unsigned char`; nothing on the right hand side of the equals sign can change that.  The value −55 (which has type `int`) is converted to `unsigned char` by the assignment, as-if by adding 256 to it, so `c1` is initialized to 201.<sup>1</sup>  You can see this for yourself by writing

   ```
   printf("%u\n", c1);
   ```

   after the initialization.
2. Both comparisons convert `c1` *back* to `int` first.  201 is representable in `int`, so the value does not change.  201 is not equal to 55 nor is it equal to −55.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, the value added is `UCHAR_MAX+1`, but it is very, very rare for that to be anything but 256 anymore.  The effect of converting a negative number from signed to unsigned is spelled out in the standard.

Comment: Several questions: 1.) What type of conversion You mention in the #1 answer? (SM, U1, U2)? 2.) Regarding answer #2 - Why is the conversion from unsigned char to int, not vice versa (from int to unsigned char)? If am right that's because the conversion always tries to be a promotion - from narrower to wider data type to avoid data loss?

Comment: @Mulligun81 (1) I don't know what you mean by SM, U1, or U2. (2) The full explanation will not fit in the comment box. There is a set of [automatic conversions](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html) that always happen when you do arithmetic in C. They are always widening conversions, and the rationale _is_ to preserve the value whenever possible, but their behavior can still be surprising so you need to know and understand the actual rules.